# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to (port 443) from /2409:(port 32948) after 6999ms

Tags: java, android

```
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
        timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 7000;
    HttpConnectionParams
        .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
    SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, httpParameters);

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
```

> It show error socket timeout error.But the same code working fine for last 5 years

Answer (score 0):

A connect timeout error happens when the server doesn't respond to the connection request in the time set. It depends on the connectivity to the other side. Your code only defines slthe time to wait. Check the network and the server.

Comment: But I am using live server. The API url working fine for IOS,only error in Android , The same source code working until march 2023 ,But after may the same code not working

Comment: Have you tested connectivity between the client and the server?